# how to save an image to firebase storage?

Tags: react-native

I have a function that allows me to select an image from the gallery or take a photo using the camera.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';

import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

export default function Upload() {
  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState();

  function imagePickerCallback(data) {
    if (data.didCancel) {
      return;
    }

    if (data.error) {
      return;
    }

    if (data.customButton) {
      return;
    }

    if (!data.assets[0].uri) {
      return;
    }

    setAvatar(data.assets[0]);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        source={{
          uri: avatar
            ? avatar.uri
            : 'https://mltmpgeox6sf.i.optimole.com/w:761/h:720/q:auto/https://redbanksmilesnj.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/man-avatar-placeholder.png',
        }}
        style={styles.avatar}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() =>
          ImagePicker.launchCamera(imagePickerCallback)
        }>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>camera</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() =>
          ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(imagePickerCallback)
        }>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>galery</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
  );
}
```

This function is working correctly, my only question is how to get this image that is being recorded inside the state avatar and save it in firebase storage generating a URL for this image?

Answer (score 1):

In order to upload an image to firebase you will first have to set it up, you can read the detailed explanation on how to achieve that here ->
https://rnfirebase.io/

Next, you will have to install the storage module, which will allow you to upload your files to firebase https://rnfirebase.io/storage/usage

Once everything is set up you can use the `firebase.storage()` directive to upload your assets.

Before the actual upload you will need to create a reference for it. A reference is a local pointer to some file on your bucket. This can either be a file that already exists or one which does not exist yet. To create a reference, use the ref method: `firebase.storage().ref(path-where-you-want-to-save-your-file)`

After the upload is complete you can use the `getDownloadURL()` function to actually get the URL you're going to use

Now you can finally upload your file using the `putFile` method. Here is an example of a helper function you could use:

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'

async function uploadImage(url) {   
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`path-where-you-want-to-save/${url}`)
  await storageRef.putFile(url)
  const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL()
  return url
}
```